# Selenium Flex API issue

Tags: apache-flex, api, selenium

Hi i am using selenium flex API integrated selenium RC.After launching the Flex application selenium fails to identify the fields inside the module box on the login page.

Eror trace:

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Error: The element 'logonId' was not found in the application

Can you please provide a solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version ( >= 0.2.5 ) of the API.

This will fix your problem as previous versions have compatibility issues with different versions of the Selenium IDE.